# StoreModule.forFeature() in SubModule and StoreModule.forRoot in AppModule results in extra level in state tree

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have project where I've created an `AuthModule` that I import into my `AppModule`. I'm configuring NGRX Store in this module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),    
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forFeature('auth', reducers)
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase }]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Then I add this `AuthModule` to my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If I import this into `AppModule` without adding `StoreModule.forRoot({})` then I get an error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[StoreFeatureModule -> ReducerManager -> ReducerManager -> ReducerManager]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager!
```

If I add the `StoreModule.forRoot({})` it resolves the error, but it seems to create an extra 'auth` node in my state tree:

```
{
  auth: {
    auth: {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: { ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing `StoreModule.forFeature('auth', reducers)` from `AuthModule` imports and adding `StoreModule.forRoot<AppState>(reducers)` to `AppModule`. I had to add a `forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AuthModule>` definition to `AuthModule`:

```
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AuthModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        AngularFireAuthModule,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

This configuration results in the state tree structure that I wanted:

```
{
  auth: {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { ...
```

What I'd really like though is for a root `app` node with the child nodes representing each Feature Module. I can't quite figure out that structure though. Any suggestions?